# Android: Enable click event on empty activity area

Tags: android, events, background, click

i set my activity theme to translucent so as to see through to the underneath activity window.

I want to know if it's possible to enable click event when user tap on empty area on this translucent activity?

Thanks,

dara kok

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to add click event to your activity. You need to do as below:

You could have done setContentView(R.layout.main); in onCreate() of your activity.

In main.xml, give some id to the root layout. For eg.,

Lets consider you have root as LinearLayout with id set as below,

Then in onCreate() of your activity, you will have to do the following:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Overriding this would work:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

However i think it's your translucent activity that will get the taps, not the one visible under it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add OnClickListener on parent view of your layout. 
For example, add `android:id="@+id/some_id"` to your parent LinearLayout in main.xml.

Then add this code after setContentView in onCreate method:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.some_id);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) linearLayout.getParent(); // Get parent FrameLayout
frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed(); // Close activity, for example
    }
});

linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // empty block for prevent frameLayout click event, if you need
    }
});
```